# ExtJs 4 - error in opening a tab in a form

Tags: forms, tabs, extjs4.2

In a web application developed on ExtJs 4.2.2 framework, when in a a complex form (with a structure composed of several tabs) I open a tab I have the following Javascript error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null

Does anybody verified this same error ? What it means ?

P.S. the tab is opened with all controls correctly displayed, but the error prevents from opening other tabs

Comment: Can you specify error line and show callstack?

Comment: It seems to be resolved... Thank You, Alexander, eventually I'll post again issue.